# Tcl: Package wrapping regsub and string map *** Looking for side effects ***

Tags: regex, tcl

I made the following package with four new commands to simplify the use of `regsub` and `map`. I been using these commands for quite a while and so far is working well. I am wondering if the code has any weaknesses that could have undesirable results or errors in the future.

regdel *varName* *args*  (remove from *varName* regex matching *args*)

mapdel *varName* *args* (remove from *varName* string matching *args*)

regrep *varName* *exp* *repl* (replace *exp* in *varName* with *repl*)

maprep *varName* *string* *repl* (replace *string* in *varName* with *repl*)

## Remove digits using regdel

```
regdel inputFile {[[:digit:]]}
```

## Remove digits using mapdel

```
mapdel inputFile 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

## Replace blank characters using regrep

```
regrep inputFile {[[:space:]]+} \n
```

## Replace blank characters using maprep

```
maprep inputFile " " \n
```

Package code:

```
package provide myregex 1.0

proc regdel {ref args} {
    upvar 1 $ref var
    foreach match $args {
        regsub -all $match $var "" var
    } 
}

proc mapdel {ref args} {
    upvar 1 $ref var
    foreach match $args {
        set var [string map [list "$match" ""] $var]
    } 
}

proc regrep {ref match repl} {
    upvar 1 $ref var 
    regsub -all $match $var $repl var
}
proc maprep {ref match repl} {
    upvar 1 $ref var
    set var [string map [list "$match" "$repl"] $var]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid collisions, I would put your procs in a namespace:

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.htm

```
package provide myregex 1.0
namespace eval myregex {
    namespace export regdel mapdel regrep maprep
    # your code here
}
```

Then, when you use it:

```
package require myregex

myregex::mapdel file foo bar baz

# or, you decide the risk of collisions in the global namespace
namespace import myregex::*
mapdel file foo bar baz
```

I'm not that keen on your proc names: `regrep` looks like `re-grep`. Consider sub-namespaces

```
namespace eval myregex {
    namespace export regex map
}

namespace eval myregex::regex {
    proc del args ...
    proc rep args ...
}

namespace eval myregex::map {
    proc del args ...
    proc rep args ...
}
```

then

```
namespace import myregex::*
map::del file foo bar baz
regex::rep file hello world
```

---

Using Donal's ensemble suggestion:

```
namespace eval myregex {
    namespace export regex map
    namespace eval regex {
        proc del {varname args} {
            if {[llength $args] == 0} return
            upvar 1 $varname var
            regsub -all [join $args "|"] $var "" var
        }
        proc rep {varname args} {
            if {[llength $args] == 0} return
            upvar 1 $varname var
            foreach {pattern replacement} $args {
                regsub -all $pattern $var $replacement var
            }
        }
        namespace ensemble create
        namespace export *
    }
    namespace eval map {
        namespace ensemble create
        proc del {varname args} {
            if {[llength $args] == 0} return
            upvar 1 $varname var
            foreach substr $args {
                lappend map $substr ""
            }
            set var [string map $map $var]
        }
        proc rep {varname args} {
            if {[llength $args] == 0} return
            upvar 1 $varname var
            set var [string map $args $var]
        }
        namespace ensemble create
        namespace export *
    }
}
```

then

```
namespace import myregex::*

set str "hello world"; regex del str l d;     puts $str
set str "hello world"; regex rep str l L o O; puts $str
set str "hello world"; map del str l d;       puts $str
set str "hello world"; map rep str l L o O;   puts $str
```

outputs

```
heo wor
heLLO wOrLd
heo wor
heLLO wOrLd
```

Comment: I'd suggest making ensembles.